# Securing Tomcat-Server where to set deployXML = false?

Tags: security, tomcat

For Securing my Apache Tomcat server on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS,

I wanted to set attribute deployXML = false, but I don't know in which xml file. In the tomcat folder, I have the files `server.xml` / `context.xml` / `web.xml` and `tomcat-user.xml` and a named folder `Catalina` with an empty `localhost` folder. In the Tomcat documentation, they describe the host attributes but I can't see where I should place my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is set in the `<Host>` container element of your `server.xml`.

Here is an snippet of the default `server.xml` with the added attribute:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
    deployXML="false" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

If the attribute is disabled, you will have to provide the (now disabled) `/META-INF/context.xml` of your webapp in the location defined by the `xmlBase` attribute.

On Debian, I had to to copy

```
cp /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
```

for the root webapp, otherwise the application won't start.

See

- [The Host Container - Standard Implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) (Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference)